# Error in payment in woocommerce subscription plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment, woocommerce-subscriptions, mercadopago

I have used Vex Soluciones Mercadopago Gateway plugin and WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin with woocommerce.there is error in payment(error en pago).what is the issue?any solution for this?
This is screenshot of error in payment.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6vbm.jpg)

Comment: What is in your logs ? Also if you have issues only with this payment method then ask the plugin author for support.

Answer (score 0):

please check the compatibility of your payment gateway with the [woocommerce subscription](https://wordpress.org/plugins/subscriptions-for-woocommerce/), as this seems to be some incompatibility issue.

Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).